# Kotlin in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am using from `kotlin` but when I sync it in my project get me bellow error :

```
Error:Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.2-3.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/D:/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1.2-3/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1.2-3.pom
    file:/D:/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1.2-3/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1.2-3.jar
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1.2-3/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1.2-3.pom
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1.2-3/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1.2-3.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

Here is my `build.gradle(Module)` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.baslam.kotlinme"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

And here is my `build.gradle(project)` :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'
```

`'1.1.2-3'` version is not available in jcenter repo neither it is available in your file system.

As I check the latest version `1.1.2-2` is available in jcenter that is last update on Apr 28, 2017 so use `1.1.2-2` version instead of `1.1.2-3`.

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-2'
```

Comment: @ Abhishek Aryan .Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just a heads up: `1.1.2-3` is now up in the repo.

Comment: @JoJoRoid `kotlin_version 1.1.2-3` now deployed, you can use now.

Comment: @Abhishek Aryan. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ICYMI, ver 1.1.2-3 is no longer supported and will give erros. Use this, as now it's 1.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin Gradle plugin version which you set is not still available on repository. 
Try setting to any other version like:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
```